# Blocking signal one time in Qt doesn't work correctly

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Hi i have following code:

```
void MainWindow::on_listWidgetNotes_currentItemChanged(QListWidgetItem *current, QListWidgetItem *previous)//Test!
{
    if(current != NULL)
    {
        ui->plainTextEditContent->setEnabled(true);
        change = false;
        if(isModified)
        {
            auto reply = QMessageBox::question(this, "Test", "Do you want save changes?", QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No|QMessageBox::Cancel);
            if (reply == QMessageBox::Yes) on_pushButtonSave_clicked();
            else if(reply == QMessageBox::No) notes.closeFile();
            else
            {
                //ui->listWidgetNotes->blockSignals(true);
                ui->listWidgetNotes->setCurrentItem(previous);
                //ui->listWidgetNotes->blockSignals(false);
                return;
            }
        }
        isModified = false;
        this->setWindowTitle(current->text()+" - VfNotes 1.0");
        ui->plainTextEditContent->setPlainText(notes.openFile(current->text()));
    }
}
```

In specified case code have to show message box and set focus on previous item, after select cancel button.

But `setCurrentItem` calls `on_listWidgetNotes_currentItemChanged` again with this message box. After use `blockSignals` focus doesn't come back on previous element. What to do to set focus on previous item after click cancel, that `on_listWidgetNotes_currentItemChanged` wasn't call again?

Answer (score 0):

So, if this is the slot that gets called when the selection changes, then instead this slot getting called , create another slot and from there, you call this function..
Now this new slot will have the previous item and from there if the function returns a book instead of void signifying that a cancel is pressed, then you call setCurrentItem again...

Comment: I see exactly the same in your 2 answers, if you want to add some information, edit your question